# Regarding a Paper by Paul.A Clement on Tridiagonal Matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

In Paul.A Clement's (1959) paper:

```
A Class of Triple-Diagonal Matrices for Test Purposes

SIAM Review, Vol. 1, No. 1 (Jan., 1959), pp. 50-52
```

He makes the claim that the eigenvalues of :

$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & y_{1} & 0 & ... & 0 \\\ 
x_{1} & 0 & y_{2} &  & ... \\\
0 & x_{2} & 0 & ... & 0 \\\ 
... &  & ... &  & y_{n-1} \\\ 
0 & ... & 0 & x_{n-1} & 0
\end{pmatrix} $

are $\pm (n), \pm (n-2), ..., (\pm1 \; or \; 0)$ for $x_{k} = k$ and $y_{k} = n-k+1$.

Specifically, and I quote, "then a theorem of Sylvester establishes that the eigenvalues of this An+, are the
numbers".

I can't for the life of me figure out what theorem and/or how it follows from them. I am familiar with Sylvester's formula for matrices in terms of their eigenvalues, but to get Frobenius covariants of a matrix A one needs to know the eigenvalues to start with.

Am I overlooking something trivial here?

Comment: This website is for questions of research interest. Your question might get a better reception at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a legit question and I don't see why it will get a better response on M.SE.

Comment: @darij, it certainly got a quicker response at m.se; I won't be drawn on whether it got a better response there. 

Comment: (of course, since all I put in my answer there were links to related papers, it can't really be said to be "better"...)

Answer (score 3):

I think the claim in this form is wrong. The eigenvalues are not integral. For example, with $n=4$ the matrix is
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 4 & 0 & 0\cr
1 & 0 & 3 & 0\cr
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \cr
0 & 0 & 3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is 
$\chi (t)=t^4-16 t^2 +24$, which has no integral roots.
Am I overlooking something ?

Edit: just visited the site http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/deli/Clement/
Here I saw that the upper diagonal must be $3,2,1$, not $4,3,2$. Then everything is OK.
So $y_k=n-k$ rather than $y_k=n-k+1$, what you wrote. We have a recursion for $\chi(t)=\det(t\cdot id-A)$, see [Eigenvalues of Symmetric Tridiagonal Matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices).

Edit: A proof for the correct claim can be found in the paper of Taussky and Todd, "Another look at a matrix of Mark Kac", Linear Algebra Appl. 150 (1991), 341-360.
More details are also at
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405670/regarding-a-paper-by-paul-a-clement-on-tridiagonal-matrices, which was remarked by Gerry (thank you ). Also, Darij's remark is correct, that the proof does not follow easily, so I have edited this here.

Comment: Why easily? Where is the symmetry?

Comment: Yes, OP posted to m.se, I posted a $3\times3$ counterexample, then the correction to the problem was noted, and a link was given to a previous m.se question about the same matrix. 

Comment: @Darij: you are right, the proof is not evident. My answer was (is) a comment about the mistake of the matrix, not more.

@Gerry: I have found your link and the answers, thank you. The correction to the problem got lost, as we see.

Comment: As you have linked to the paper by Taussky and Todd, you might want to mention http://www-math.mit.edu/~edelman/homepage/papers/kac.pdf as well...
