# How can I calculate eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, tridiagonal-matrices

Are there special methods to get exact eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955168/how-to-prove-the-eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-matrix

Comment: It is easier when the matrix is also Toeplitz.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. For general tridiagonal matrices, see The Numerical Recipes, Chapter 11, or Golub-Van Loan. For *symmetric* tridiagonal matrices, you can do better, see Coakley/Rochlin's paper.

*Coakley, Ed S.; Rokhlin, Vladimir*, [**A fast divide-and-conquer algorithm for computing the spectra of real symmetric tridiagonal matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.acha.2012.06.003), Appl. Comput. Harmon. Anal. 34, No. 3, 379-414 (2013). [ZBL1264.65051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1264.65051).

*Golub, Gene; Van Loan, Charles F.*, Matrix computations., Baltimore, MD: The Johns Hopkins Univ. Press. xxvii, 694 p. (1996). [ZBL0865.65009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0865.65009).

Comment: Is there something about nonsymmetric tridiagonal matrices in Golub-Van Loan? I thought not.