# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of tridiagonal matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, eigenvector, tridiagonal-matrices

What can I say about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the tridiagonal matrix $T$ given as
$T = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
c_1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
& c_2 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} \\
& & & c_{n-1} & a_n
\end{pmatrix}$.

If I set $a_i = 0$, do you know any previous results?

I know some results for simple cases like constant elements or symmetric matrices, but I would like to know if there are any results for more general cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281982/how-can-i-calculate-eigenvalues-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix)

Comment: I believe that the references mentioned in that post are related to symmetric tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: I'll retract my vote.

Comment: I'm not sure it may be of any help, but if you further assume that $T$ is normal, which requires that $|c_i|=|b_i|$ for all $i$, then you can split $T$ as $T=S+A$ with $S$ (resp. $A$) tridiagonal symmetric (resp. antisymmetric) with $A,S$ diagonalizable in the same basis. This simplifies quite a lot the problem. In the non-normal case, the eigenvectors may not be orthogonal and I fear no particular structure would arise.

Comment: If $b_i$ and $c_i$ have the same sign for all $i$, then I think you can apply a diagonal rescaling to make it symmetric => it has real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your question has already been answered here:

[Eigenvalues of Symmetric Tridiagonal Matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices)

No results for general tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the difference between my question and this one is that I am not considering symmetric matrices.

Comment: @Guilherme Sure, but if there is no general results for symmetric tridiagonal matrices, a fortiori there is no results for non-symmetric ones, isn't it?

Comment: You are correct. I missed that point. Thanks for pointing this.