# Upper Bounds on the Largest Eigenvalue of Jacobi Matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, tridiagonal-matrices

Suppose I have a symmetric tridiagonal (Jacobi) matrix in the following form:

$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_{1} & 0 & ... & 0 \\\ 
a_{1} & 1 & a_{2} &  & ... \\\
0 & a_{2} & 1 & ... & 0 \\\ 
... &  & ... &  & a_{n-1} \\\ 
0 & ... & 0 & a_{n-1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}, $

where all $0< a_i < 1$ for $i = 1\ldots n-1$ but the matrix is not necessarily diagonally dominant. I am interested in finding a tight upper-bound for the largest eigenvalue of this matrix.

Unfortunately, [Eigenvalues of Symmetric Tridiagonal Matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices) doesn't have the answer that I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entries are nonnegative, so the dominant eigenvector has
all entries positive, and its eigenvalue is an increasing function of the $a_i$.
If each $a_i = 1$ then that eigenvalue is $1 + 2 \cos\frac\pi{n+1}$
if I did this right; since you allow only $a_i < 1$, this bound
$1 + 2 \cos\frac\pi{n+1}$ is not attained, but it is still the supremum of
eigenvalues of such matrices.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your argument, I will use a slightly tighter bound $1+2a_{\max}\cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}$ where $a_{\max} = \max_{i=1\ldots n-1}a_{i}$.

Comment: Dear Noam, do you have any recommendation of reference that presents results on eigenvalues of Jacobi matrices?

Comment: Sorry I don't, and I'm even less able to find such references now
than I would have B.C. (Before COVID-19) . . .