The eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrices
Can we determine the number of positive eigenvalues for the following tridiagonal matrix under some criterion in terms of $a_i,b_i,c_i$:
$$
A_n=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1} \\\ 
c_{1} & a_{2} & b_{2}  \\\
& c_{2} & a_{3} & \ddots \\\ 
& & \ddots & \ddots & b_{n-1} \\\ 
& & & c_{n-1} & a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This question is inspired by matters at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices
