Diagonalize almost symmetric tridiagonal matrix
I begin with an $n \times n$ real symmetric tridiagonal matrix. However, I replace the non-zero elements in the first and last rows with zeros, so it is no longer symmetric
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & & & \\
 b_1 & a_2 & b_2 & & & \\
& & \ddots & & \\
& & b_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1} \\
& & &  0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$$.

Is it possible to diagonalize this matrix to find $M = Q D Q^{-1}$ in $O(n^2)$ operations?
If the $b_i$ are all positive and the $a_i$ all negative, can we be sure that there are $n$ real (non-positive) eigenvalues?

The background is this is a numerical discretization of the Laplacian with specific boundary conditions. For this reason, in my example, the $b_i$ and $a_i$ are related approximately (not exactly) by $a_i \approx -2 b_i$.

Start with the matrix
$$
M' =
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\
0 & a_2 & b_2 \\
& & \ddots \\
& & b_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & 0 \\
& & & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
i.e. your matrix $M$ but with the two entries on the edges deleted. This is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix, so it can be diagonalized in $O(n^2)$ and has $n$ real eigenvalues. You can easily check that $M$ and $M'$ have the same eigenvalues ($tI-M$ can be transformed to $tI-M'$ with two elementary row operations).
Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis vectors. The matrix $M'$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue with eigenvectors $e_1$ and $e_n$, and $n-2$ additional eigenvalues $\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_{n-1}$ with corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors $v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}$. Since $M$ is nonsymmetric, its left and right eigenvectors are different. The right eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_k$ is still $v_k$, but the left eigenvector changes to
$$
u_k^*=\lambda_k v_k^* + b_1 (v_k^* e_2) e_1^* + b_n (v_k^* e_{n-1}) e_n^*.
$$
Each of these vectors can obviously be computed in $O(n)$ once $\lambda_k$ and $v_k$ are known, for a total of $O(n^2)$ taking all $n-2$ such vectors into account. In order to prove that $u_k^*$ is really a left eigenvector, just write $M'=\sum_k \lambda_k v_k v_k^*$ and $M=M'+b_1 e_2 e_1^*+b_ne_{n-1}e_n^*$, then check that $u_k^* M = \lambda_k u_k^*$ (using the fact that $e_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1},e_n$ is an orthonormal basis).
Finally, we need to compute the left and right eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$. This time the left eigenvectors are unchanged, i.e. $e_1^*$ and $e_n^*$, but the right eigenvectors change. We are looking for vectors $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ such that $Mx=0$, i.e.
$$
\begin{align*}
b_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + b_2 x_3 &= 0 \\
b_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 + b_3 x_4 &= 0 \\
&\dots \\
b_{n-2} x_{n-2} + a_{n-1} x_{n-1} + b_{n-1} x_n &= 0.
\end{align*}
$$
We can thus recursively compute $x_k$ from $x_{k-1}$ and $x_{k-2}$. Starting with the two pairs of initial values $x_1=1,x_2=0$ and $x_1=0,x_2=1$ will therefore give us two eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ in $O(n)$.
As to the question of whether the eigenvalues are nonpositive, here is a counterexample:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Excellent! What algorithm can I use to diagonalise $M'$ in $O(n^2)$? Thank you

This is implemented in LAPACK and is also available in SciPy. If you want to read about the actual algorithm then look at the papers cited in the LAPACK link.

Actually what I wrote about using Bunch-Nielsen-Sorensen doesn't quite work because the eigenvalues don't change, but I'm pretty sure this can be fixed. I'll think about it and edit my answer later.

I use python so the SciPy link is very helpful thank you. You are right that I don't need to know the mechanics of the algorithm itself, but just to be able to get the solution fast in code. If you manage to work out the final step, how to convert the eigenvectors for $M'$ into the eigenvectors for $M$ it would be fantastic! I will also try to make progress myself with simple algebra

On the non-positivity of the eigenvalues, I found this helpful answer that should allow me to make progress
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices/474235#474235

The eigenvector computation should be fixed now. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Thank you for such a beautifully clear answer and for lending me your time and brain power
